# VSTest task in Azure pipeline with NUnit3 test adapter not working as expected

Tags: azure-devops, vstest

I am using VSTest@2 in my build pipeline to run NUnit3 tests using NUnit3 test adapter. The task looks something like this

```
- task: VSTest@2
      displayName: Catch all
      inputs:
        testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
        testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory!=Common'
        testAssemblyVer2: |
          $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\Drop\binaries\Testing1.UnitTests.dll
          !**\*TestAdapter.dll
          !**\obj\**
        searchFolder: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\Drop\binaries'
        vsTestVersion: 'toolsInstaller'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
        uiTests: true
        rerunFailedTests: false
        codeCoverageEnabled: false
        otherConsoleOptions: $(testOtherConsoleOptions)
        pathtoCustomTestAdapters: 'C:\TestAdapter'
```

Test adapter is in C:\TestAdapter folder. Even though 'searchFolder' is defined, when tests are running, they are running with respect to working directory of Source (which is 's' in Azure pipelines). Some of these tests are trying to open some test files but they are failing with 'file not found' because that file is present in the folder specified in 'searchFolder' and the test is looking into say 'C:\source\1\s'

However, if I use NUnit2 tests and NUnit 2 test adapter then all the tests are passing. No path related issues.

Did anybody faced this issue?